# I am stuck with the upgrade

Tags: 7, upgrading

I am upgrading a site from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7, following the instructions here: https://www.drupal.org/node/570162

When running update.php it gets stuck on the first step 'Updating user module' at 0%. I'm wondering if this might be because the site has about 400,000 registered users (another issue there I need to fix), or if something else is going on to prevent it from updating. Perhaps the message

`Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 416 of 427 bytes in variable_initialize() (line 935 of /services/webpages/util/5/4/54ev547u.myutilitydomain.com/livemusicashland.com/ifollo/public/includes/bootstrap.inc).`

has something to do with it? It's my first attempt at updating from one major Drupal version to another, so I'll take any advice I can get. Thanks!

[image: Here's a link to a screen capture]

Comment: Drupal is choking on serialized variable in your `variable` table. With some well-placed print statements, you can probably find the source variable and fix it. There might be bigger problems, but that's can told from that error.

Comment: Thanks for that advice! I think it might have to do with me trying to log out after deleting my Drupal 6 files and uploading my D7 but not yet running update.php.

Comment: As far as the slow update goes, it does appear to be related to the huge amount of users and updating their info in the database. It took over an hour just for the user module, but now the install is moving along much quicker. I'm hoping the 'variable' error is cleared after the update.

Comment: You may want to try [Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) if you haven't already. It really helps with many of these types of tasks including db updates and migrations.